# Laravel 5 - firstOrCreate() and delete old items?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Really not sure how to approach this, but I have a meta table with entry_id(foreign key) and key/value like this:

```
id | entry_id |     key     |     value     
-------------------------------------------
1       4         Fruit 1       Apple
2       4         Fruit 2       Banana
3       4         Fruit 3       Cantaloupe
```

I want to update the `entry_id 4` with the new list of key/value pairs `Fruit 1/Apple` and `Fruit 4/Dragonfruit`, which would look like this:

```
id | entry_id |     key     |     value     
-------------------------------------------
 1      4         Fruit 1       Apple
 4      4         Fruit 4       Dragonfruit
```

So here are the 3 things that should happen:

- `Fruit 1/Apple` did not change, so it should remain the same.
- `Fruit 4/Dragonfruit` is new on the list, so it should be added.
- The new updated list does not have `Fruit 2/Banana` or `Fruit 3/Cantaloupe`, so they should to be removed.

I tried using `firstOrCreate()` like this:

```
// $metas is an array of the new list
foreach ($metas as $meta) {
  $entry->entryMeta()->firstOrCreate([
    'entry_id' => $entry->id,
    'key' => $meta->key,
    'value' => $meta->value
  ]);
}
```

Which takes care of the first 2 bullet points of 3 things that should happen. The last bullet point of removing old items that aren't in the new list does not work (which I understand as it isn't part of `firstOrCreate()`).

Any idea how to take care of all 3 bullet points?

Comment: Do you require that the id remain the same for existing entries and remain auto incrementing for new entries?

Comment: Additionally, you only want to change those rows that have the 'entry_id' you are working with while other rows will remain unchanged, please let me know if this is correct to make sure I understand

Comment: @tam Yup, I honestly don't care much for the id, I just didn't want to reinsert something that was there (maybe it's more work to do that on the system every time an item is updated, just wiping everything clean and reinserting?) Correct for your second comment, I will only be dealing with key/values rows belonging to a single `entry_id` at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you essentially want to replace all entries in the table that have the `entry_id == x`, the simplest solution might be something like this on your model:

```
public function updateEntry(int $entryId, array $newFruits)
{
    // delete old entries
    self::where('entry_id', $entryId)->delete();

    // create new ones
    foreach ($newFruits as $fruit) {
        self::save($fruit);
    }
}
```

If for whatever reason there existed extra data on existing rows that you do not intend to replace, then you could potentially modify this method check the `$newFruits` to see if it had values that represent something already in your table. Meaning in your case, you would check for both `key` and `value` and if they already exist as a pair in the db, you wouldn't delete it. However, based on the table structure you provided this does not seem necessary and is just an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Thanks @tam, simple enough, I think I over complicated this one!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is, get the ids of the new fruits array and then do a whereNotIn on the table based on the id ( assuming your ids remain the same on both occasions ) and delete the results
for example,

> $updateArray = NewFruits->get()->lists('id')->toArray();
>
> $deleteFruits = Fruit::whereNotIn('id', $updateArray)->get();
>
> foreach($deleteFruits as $deleteFruit) {
>
> $deleteFruit->delete();
>
> }

Comment: I think the only issue is that I don't have the new fruits ids as the id field is just an auto incrementing value on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems like a classic case where you should just truncate the table first then run your query with the entries you want to keep.

```
DB::statement("SET foreign_key_checks = 0");

//Model::truncate(); 

Db::table('mytable')->truncate();

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
```

Then run your code again with the new improved listings. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I can't just truncate the entire table as there are other entries as well in the same table with other key/values.